# Define using {{}} is not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular9

In my below code I am getting error on referring the 'name'. And it is getting displayed as it is`{{name}}`.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = name>
<p>{{name}}</p>.
```

How to refer a dynamic value of name variable in above?

I am using

Angular CLI: 9.1.3
Node: 13.13.0.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read through this first and try to update your question with a minimum reproducible example of what you have tried so far - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you defined an attribute call name in your component class?

Comment: show us the .ts file